# About the Michel Thomas German course. Does he have a good accent?

Tags: learning, accent

[A video of Michel Thomas teaching, one in the black coat](https://youtu.be/MXIDHToE2yw)

I struggle to learn unless I know I'm listening to a person with a good accent. In other words, are there any foreign accent in his speech. It's eccentric of me to not be able to listen to people with an accent, I'm sorry, I just wanted some help from German learners and speakers how Michel Thomas accent is, despite the fact I know his teaching methods are great.
I just want to get the accent right for me when I'm learning German. It's important for me.

Comment: @HalvarF: I tend to agree. It might be more appropriate to ask if he has a foreign accent or a noticeable regional accent. He was born in 1914, by the way.

Comment: He talks like my grand dad used to.i am amazed by his quick and flawless context/ language switches.

Comment: @RDBury Yes, that's what I meant. Does he have a foreign accent? But I don't mind any regional accent, or at all mind him speaking like a person 100 years ago, as long as he's speaking German 100 years ago like how they spoken it! And it is not an opinion based question. You either have the country's accent right or not, or maybe 90% of it, with 10% foreign accent like many American born Chinese or Japanese people have. It's not hard to understand

Comment: Even his English sounds German :)

Answer (score 5):

His pronunciation is perfect, and he speaks clean Hochdeutsch. According to the [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Thomas), he was born in 1914 and lived in Breslau (now Wrocław; it was a German city inhabited by Germans at that time) as as child and teenager between age 7 and 19, so it's no wonder he learned perfect German. His English seems to have a very slight German accent, but I don't hear any accent in his German.

Of course, he was born in 1914, so it's not a very contemporary way of speaking German. Whether that's a problem for you or not depends on what your goals are.

(For context, I'm a native speaker who has lived in different parts of Germany.)

Comment: As a native German speaker I totally agree: *His pronunciation is perfect, and he speaks clean Hochdeutsch.*

Comment: thanks for the comment